# Screen actions do not show the desired behavior (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

All right with you?
I have a problem with AngularJS.
The screen has the following behavior: when clicking on the button to recover the password, the loading screen is loaded for about 60 seconds and then gives the error message, and the email was sent.

This code snippet is from a service, responsible for password recovery by email.
I intend to resolve the error but I don't know how to start. The code was already ready.

**service**

```
forgot: async (params) => {
    var deferred = Q.defer()
    var appData = {}
    const pool = await poolPromise
    if (pool) {
        var password = generator.generate({
            length: 6,
            numbers: true
        })
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
            var user = await userService.getUserByMail(params.email)
            .then((user) => {
                $scope.dadosold = response
                $scope.dadosold.forEach(element => {
                  element.datainicio = new Date(element.datainicio)
                  element.datainicio.setDate(element.datainicio.getDate() + 2)
                });
              })
            if (user) {
                var r = pool.request()
                r.input('senha', sql.NVarChar, hash)
                r.input('id', sql.Int, user[0].id)
                await r.query('UPDATE users SET senha = @senha where id = @id')
                if (!err) {
                    appData.error = 0
                    appData['data'] = 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!'
                    deferred.resolve(appData)
                    try {
                        let mailOptions = {
                            from: '"Automed" <notifier@automed.com.br>',
                            to: user[0].email,
                            subject: 'Automed - Acesso',
                            html: 'Olá ' + user[0].nome + ',<br><br><br>Sua nova senha para acesso ao sistema é: <b>' + password + '</b><br><br><br><a href="#">Ir para o Automed</a><br><br>FAVOR NÃO RESPONDER ESSA MENSAGEM.' // html body
                        }
                        let newdata = user[0]
                        newdata.senha = hash
                        auditService.insertAudit(user[0].id, "users", "Nova Senha", JSON.stringify(user[0]), JSON.stringify(newdata))
                        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                            if (error) {
                                logger.error(error)
                            }

                        });
                    } catch (err) {
                        logger.error(error)
                    }

                } else {
                    appData.error = 1
                    appData['data'] = err
                    deferred.resolve(appData)
                }


            } else {
                appData.error = 2
                appData['data'] = 'Usuário não cadastrado.'
                deferred.resolve(appData)
            }
        })

    }
    else {
        appData['error'] = 3
        appData['data'] = 'Internal Server Error'
        deferred.resolve(appData)
    }
    return deferred.resolve()
}
```

**front-end controller**

```
$scope.esqueciSenha = function (row) {
    $scope.erro = "";
    $scope.success = "";
    if (row != undefined && row.email != undefined) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        AuthService.Forgot(row)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                $scope.response = null;
                row.email = "";
                service.showToast("success", "Você receberá um e-mail com a sua senha de acesso.");
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                $scope.response = null;
                try {
                    if (err.data.error == 2)
                    service.showToast("erro", "E-mail não cadastrado");
                } catch (err) {
                    service.showToast("erro", "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar realizar o login. Favor entrar em contato com o suporte.");
                }
            });

    } else
        $scope.erro = "Favor preencher todos os campos.";

}
```

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

Comment: The ES6 promises created by `async`/`await` are not integrated with the AngularJS execution context. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.